# Unable to GetToken from QuickBooks QBOConceptsTutorial-DotNet Sample Application

Tags: token, quickbooks-online

I am trying to learn how to work with QuickBooks API calls to integrate my own application with the platform's backend for invoicing and Customer records requests.  I started with the Developer Web site from Quickbooks and landed on their GIT repository area, where I downloaded the QBOConceptsTutorial-DotNet Sample Application.  Initially, the Application wowuld not start or load, failing on the HTTPS call.  Therefore, I created a new similar applicaion on Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition and replicated all the necessary code to it.  then my new application started properly and I was able to connect to my QuickBooks Sandbox Company with the Sandbox user id and secret credentials.
I received a callback set of variables with no errors.  However, when I click on the Get Token model, the failure happened at the following new TokenClient() call.  The error from the Web app is posted below.  Can I get some assistance and guidance on solving this issue?

```
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(AppController.tokenEndpoint, AppController.clientid, AppController.clientsecret);
```

```
Line 68:{
Line 69:             //Request Oauth2 tokens
Line 70:             var tokenClient = new TokenClient(AppController.tokenEndpoint, AppController.clientid, AppController.clientsecret);
Line 71: 
Line 72: 

Source File: D:\Source\Repos\QBOAPI\QBOAPI\Controllers\CallbackController.cs    Line: 70

Stack Trace:


[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration Serilog.FileLoggerConfigurationExtensions.File(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSinkConfiguration, System.String, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel, System.String, System.IFormatProvider, System.Nullable`1<Int64>, Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch, Boolean, Boolean, System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>, Serilog.RollingInterval, Boolean, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.Text.Encoding, Serilog.Sinks.File.FileLifecycleHooks)'.]
   Intuit.Ipp.OAuth2PlatformClient.Diagnostics.OAuthAdvancedLogging..ctor(Boolean enableSerilogRequestResponseLoggingForDebug, Boolean enableSerilogRequestResponseLoggingForTrace, Boolean enableSerilogRequestResponseLoggingForConsole, Boolean enableSerilogRequestResponseLoggingForFile, String serviceRequestLoggingLocationForFile) in C:\Users\nshrivastava\Documents\GitHub\QuickBooks-V3-DotNET-SDK\IPPDotNetDevKitCSV3\Code\Intuit.Ipp.OAuth2PlatformClient.Diagnostics\OAuthAdvancedLogging.cs:238
   Intuit.Ipp.OAuth2PlatformClient.TokenClient..ctor(String endpoint, HttpMessageHandler innerHttpMessageHandler) in C:\Users\nshrivastava\Documents\GitHub\QuickBooks-V3-DotNET-SDK\IPPDotNetDevKitCSV3\Code\Intuit.Ipp.OAuth2PlatformClient\Client\TokenClient.cs:52
   Intuit.Ipp.OAuth2PlatformClient.TokenClient..ctor(String endpoint, String clientId, String clientSecret, HttpMessageHandler innerHttpMessageHandler, AuthenticationStyle style) in C:\Users\nshrivastava\Documents\GitHub\QuickBooks-V3-DotNET-SDK\IPPDotNetDevKitCSV3\Code\Intuit.Ipp.OAuth2PlatformClient\Client\TokenClient.cs:90
   Intuit.Ipp.OAuth2PlatformClient.TokenClient..ctor(String endpoint, String clientId, String clientSecret, AuthenticationStyle style) in C:\Users\nshrivastava\Documents\GitHub\QuickBooks-V3-DotNET-SDK\IPPDotNetDevKitCSV3\Code\Intuit.Ipp.OAuth2PlatformClient\Client\TokenClient.cs:77
   QBOAPI.Controllers.<Token>d__17.MoveNext() in D:\Source\Repos\QBOAPI\QBOAPI\Controllers\CallbackController.cs:70
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +80
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +396
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +646
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +182
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while using QuickBooks API SDK.

In my case, it was a mismatch in versions of Serilog in my own project and in the Quickbooks SDK.

My project was using Serilog.Sinks.File(5.0.0) while the SDK was using Serilog.Sinks.File(4.1.0).

I resolved this by downgrading the Serilog package reference in my own project to match that used in the SDK - version 4.1.0.

You could also take the SDK and generate your own DLLs to use in your project with the updated Serilog packages.